# Flutter get device serial number or any other unique identifier

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am making an app where the user has to register their device first and I can block user if they use device that are not registered, and therefore I need some unique ID from their device. I used [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) and [unique_identifier](https://pub.dev/packages/unique_identifier) packages and got some unique information from the device. The problem is the user have no way of obtaining the information needed for registration like the one gotten from unique_identifier(ANDROID_ID).

Is there a way to obtain hardware serial number programmatically? Because that seems to be the only one usable for this case, or is there any other unique ID to identify a device that is obtainable both from user and programmatically?

Comment: Have you tryed device_information? The IMEI number is what you need

Comment: I read somewhere that on ios it will not be generated or sometimes can be null.

Comment: You can't, in fact, get a proper serial number on ios, it is pretty "secure", for those things

Comment: Is there any other solution? Something that can be used for both ios and android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [uuid](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid).
Than call this method to obtain an unique id based on the device (it does not contain device's hardware data but:

```
String uuid = const Uuid().v1();
```

Comment: But can I obtain this unique ID from the device? I mean as a user, not programmatically

Comment: I believe it is not possible, but I am not sure.